# lightbox2 with rails,pop up with external image(url) failed at first time click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, image, lightbox

I use rails4, ruby2.1.0 and gem [lightbox2-rails](https://github.com/gavinkflam/lightbox2-rails) to do the pop up window with external image.

It works fine with a small issues: not working for the first click.

the problem is when the page is loaded(with thumbnail as a link), the first time i click the thumbnail, it opened the image url and did not pop up a window(looks like the lightbox failed to work),

then after i return back, the lightbox starts to work, all popup function works perfectly.

So it only FAILED the first time, which is very wired! help!!!

```
            <%= link_to @images[0], data: {lightbox: "main-image"},:id=>"aaa" do%>
                <%= image_tag(@images[0],width:"100%",id: "head-view")%>
            <%end%>
```

@images[0] is one image external url, "data-lightbox" attribute is required by [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

the application js and css in rails:

```
//js    
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require owl.carousel
//= require lightbox
//= require_tree .

/*css*/
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require owl.carousel
 *= require owl.theme
 *= require lightbox
```

What's going on here? any idea?

Comment: Is there a jQuery snippet involved to activate the carousel? If so, hard code it, as Rails will process hard-coding last. If it is just included, Rails will process it first and possibly before the images are loaded.

Comment: @oMiKeY I have changed to prettyPhoto rather than lightbox, and all good now. Another problem, is the image is not perfect fit the pop up continer, instead it float to the right a light bit. But its looks okey. Thanks

Comment: let me see an html snippet i might be able to fix that for you. just update the question and i'll update my answer